# Laravel Vue component Questions about how to register

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I set up a vue on Laravel.

```
/resources/js/app.js

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

**.default** does this mean?

I couldn't find it in the document either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

As part of the vue-loader 15 updates, if your code uses the CommonJS syntax for importing EcmaScript modules, you'll need to append .default

https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/upgrade